# dc.js number display not showing up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm displaying data using d3, dc.js etc. I have a working lineChart / geoChoroplethChart but for some reason I can't get the number display to work. I'm thinking the formatting might be to blame, I've got fairly large numbers ~billions. I tried setting the d3.format to ".0e" etc but no luck.

```
var ndx = crossfilter(tradeData);
var all = ndx.groupAll();
var tradeQuantityGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) { 
  return d["quantity"];
});
var totalTradeQuantity_ND = dc.numberDisplay("quantity-nd");

totalTradeQuantity_ND
.formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
.valueAccessor(function(d){return d; })
.group(tradeQuantityGroup)
.formatNumber(d3.format(".0e"));
```

Comment: That does specify [zero precision](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format) but I'd expect to see something. Do you get a result with other formats? `.3s` might be nice for e.g. "1.17B"

Comment: Also, the selector in `dc.numberDisplay("quantity-nd") ` is probably wrong - you probably want `"#quantity-nd"`.